# Change the profile cover image dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress, function

does someone know how to change an image header dynamically depends by specific categories, 
ex: image1 for red category, image2 for blue category, image3 for green category?
Im using ultimate member plugin but don't well php coding
I have found the original code

```
function um_profile_header_cover_area( $args ) { 
global $ultimatemember;          
if ( $args['cover_enabled'] == 1 ) { 

$default_cover = um_get_option('default_cover'); 
$overlay = '<span class="um-cover-overlay"> 
<span class="um-cover-overlay-s"> 
<ins> 
<i class="um-faicon-picture-o"></i> 
<span class="um-cover-overlay-t">'.__('Change your cover photo', 'ultimatemember').'</span> 
</ins> 
</span> 
</span>'; 
?> 
<div class="um-cover <?php if ( um_profile('cover_photo') || ( $default_cover && $default_cover['url'] ) ) echo 'has-cover'; ?>" data-user_id="<?php echo um_profile_id(); ?>" data-ratio="<?php echo $args['cover_ratio']; ?>"> 

<?php do_action('um_cover_area_content', um_profile_id() ); ?> 

<?php 
if ( $ultimatemember->fields->editing ) { 
$items = array( 
'<a href="#" class="um-manual-trigger" data-parent=".um-cover" data-child=".um-btn-auto-width">'.__('Change cover photo', 'ultimatemember').'</a>',  
'<a href="#" class="um-reset-cover-photo" data-user_id="'.um_profile_id().'">'.__('Remove', 'ultimatemember').'</a>', 
'<a href="#" class="um-dropdown-hide">'.__('Cancel', 'ultimatemember').'</a>',  
); 

echo $ultimatemember->menu->new_ui( 'bc', 'div.um-cover', 'click', $items ); 
} 
?> 
<?php $ultimatemember->fields->add_hidden_field( 'cover_photo' ); ?> 

<?php echo $overlay; ?> 

<div class="um-cover-e"> 
<?php if ( um_profile('cover_photo') ) { ?> 

<?php 
if( $ultimatemember->mobile->isMobile() ) { 
if ( $ultimatemember->mobile->isTablet() ) { 
echo um_user('cover_photo', 1000); 
echo um_user('cover_photo', 300); 
} 
} else { 
echo um_user('cover_photo', 1000); 
}         
?> 

<?php } elseif ( $default_cover && $default_cover['url'] ) { 
$default_cover = $default_cover['url'];    
 echo '<img src="'. $default_cover . '" alt="" />'; 

} else { 

if ( !isset( $ultimatemember->user->cannot_edit ) ) { ?> 
<a href="#" class="um-cover-add um-manual-trigger" data-parent=".um-cover" data-child=".um-btn-auto-width"><span class="um-cover-add-i"><i class="um-icon-plus um-tip-n" title="<?php _e('Upload a cover photo', 'ultimatemember'); ?>"></i></span></a> 

<?php } 
} ?> 
</div></div> 
 <?php   
}}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: read wordpress conditional tags documentations https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags